# How to return all organizations that user is member of - Spring data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, orm, spring-data-jpa

So, I have a user entity, and an organization entity. The organization contains a collection of users (the members of the organization.) There is a many to many relationship between the two, but the user entity does not contain any collection of organizations.

There is of course, a join table of organization ids and user ids to see what organizations contain what users.

How can I use a spring data jpa repository interface method to return all organizations which contain a given user id?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Query("select o from Organization o join o.users u on u = ?1")
List<Organization> findAllOrganizationsByUser(User user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Projections and write a findby* method in your interface.

Projections
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections

Find By
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods